# Smart text replacing with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to replace some part of text, e.g. mustache var {{myvar}}, on already loaded page.
Example html:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>{{MYTITLE}}</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <p><strong><ul><li>text {{TEXT}}</li></ul></strong></p>
      {{ANOTHER}}
   </body>
</html>
```

#### What's the problem? Use `$(html).html(myrenderscript($(html).html()))`!

It's ugly, slow and brokes `<script>` tags.

#### What do you want?

I want to get closest tag with {{}} and than render and replace.

#### Your researches?

Firstly, i tried: `$('html :contains("{{"))`. But it returns `<title>, <p>, <strong>` .... But i need `<title>` and `<li>`.

Than i tried to filter them:

```
$('html :contains("{{")').filter(function (i) {
   return $(this).find(':contains("{{")').length === 0
});
```

...but it WONT return `{{ANOTHER}}`. And that is my dead end. Your suggestions?

Comment: it is not a complete one, but could work in this case `$('html :contains("{{")').not(':has(*)')`

Comment: @sroes seems yes) and it will be good to exclude `{{TEXT}}` than;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-replacetext-plugin/ you could do the following:

```
$('html *').replaceText(/{{([^}]+)}}/, function(fullMatch, key) {
    return key;
}, true);
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/4nvNy/

Comment: Thank you - I just pulled it from my code library and couldn't remember who I got it from - I have lost a load of comments from my code snippets when I did an over-exhuberant 'find replace' on comments :-P +1 to your answer as I think you understood the OP even better than me :-P

Comment: Awesome. Works like a charm)

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is replace that text - then surely the following works (or have I mis-understood)

usage is as follows: CONTAINER (body) - replaceTExt (search term (I have built the function to always include {{}} around the term), (replace - this will remove the {{}} as well)

```
$('body').replaceText("MYTITLE","WHATEVER YOU WANT IT REPLACING WITH");

$.fn.replaceText = function(search, replace, text_only) {  
return this.each(function(){  
    var v1, v2, rem = [];
    $(this).find("*").andSelf().contents().each(function(){
        if(this.nodeType === 3) {
            v1 = this.nodeValue;
            v2 = v1.replace("{{" + search + "}}", replace );
            if(v1!=v2) {
                if(!text_only && /<.*>/.test(v2)) {  
                    $(this).before( v2 );  
                    rem.push(this);  
                }
                else this.nodeValue = v2;  
            }
        }
    });
    if(rem.length) $(rem).remove();
});
};
```

Comment: Very near, i had an 'assoc array' like `{search: replacement}`. I'll try your code as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You could avoid jQuery altogether if you wanted to with something like this:

```
<body>


<p><strong>
    <ul>
        <li>text {{TEXT}}</li>
    </ul>
</strong></p>
{{ANOTHER}}

<hr/>
<div id="showResult"></div>

<script>


    var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML;
    var startIdx = 0, endIdx = 0, replaceArray = [];
    var scriptPos = body.indexOf('<script');
    while (startIdx != 1) {
        startIdx = body.indexOf('{{', endIdx) + 2;
        if(startIdx > scriptPos){
            break;
        }
        endIdx = body.indexOf('}}', startIdx);
        var keyText = body.substring(startIdx, endIdx);
        replaceArray.push({"keyText": keyText, 'startIdx': startIdx, 'endIdx': endIdx});

    }

    document.getElementById("showResult").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(replaceArray);


</script>

</body>
```

You can then do what you want with the replaceArray.